# How to show labels above pie chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, chart.js, pie-chart

I am using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#pie) and [react-charts-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2) in my React app to make Pie chart, how can I show labels name outside every section of pie chart like this:
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUpxm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can checkout this plugin to display the labels outside pie chart in chartjs.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels to add it in the react-charts-2 you can use its **plugins prop**.

Don't know how to pass props then please checkout https://react-chartjs-2.netlify.app/components/pie#props to know how to pass props in Component.

Comment: thank you I will look into this, does using outside labels remove legend above pie chart?

Comment: yes, it will remove the inside labels